# Use a non-public array from another module within a new module

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, module

I am following a tutorial on VBA static arrays.  I want to make sure my thought process is correct for something simple that I wish to do.

I have code that picks up all 12 months and places it into a static array of type string.  As practice, I wanted to see if it's possible to copy these values onto another location using another module that acts as "pasting" the months at the cursor selection, but not utilizing a public array.  I'm new to VBA so perhaps my way of think about coding is flawed and for such a purpose, I should be using a publicly defined array.

```
Sub PopulateStaticArray()
Dim months(11) As String
Dim ndx As Integer
Dim xrow As Long
ndx = 0
xrow = 2
Do Until Cells(xrow, 1).Value = ""
    months(ndx) = Cells(xrow, 1).Value
ndx = ndx + 1
xrow = xrow + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

What I want to achieve in a redundant fashion. (I'm essentially recreating the array from scratch).

```
Sub InsertMonthsArray()
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim rowNum As Double
    Dim colNum As Double
    Dim months(11) As String
    ActiveCell.Select
    rowNum = ActiveCell.Row
    colNum = ActiveCell.Column
    months(0) = "January"
    months(1) = "February"
    months(2) = "March"
    months(3) = "April"
    months(4) = "May"
    months(5) = "June"
    months(6) = "July"
    months(7) = "August"
    months(8) = "September"
    months(9) = "October"
    months(10) = "November"
    months(11) = "December"
    For counter = 0 To UBound(months, 1)
        Cells(rowNum, colNum).Value = months(counter)
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Next counter
End Sub
```

I read some posts about passing arrays, but I'm not sure if that's achieving what I'm looking for.  Of course this is not actual project, but just to improve my understanding of the interaction between modules within VBA for Excel.  I don't necessary need any code, but just the general conceptual guidance on if I should be using some other method to achieve this task (i.e. Public defined Array or Functions, etc.) Thank you.

Comment: You are not creating a static array inside `PopulateStaticArray`. The `months` is destroyed as soon as you exit the sub. If you want to pass an already existing array to `InsertMonthsArray()`, regardless of where it comes from, then yes, that should be `Sub InsertMonthsArray(months() as string)`.

Comment: Posted a modified solution in addition to @GSerg 's valuable comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GSerg mentioned correctly

> "You are not creating a static array inside PopulateStaticArray. If you want to pass an already existing array to InsertMonthsArray(), regardless of where it comes from, then yes, that should be Sub InsertMonthsArray(months() as string)"

You need to pass your array - declared at procedure level - as (implicit) `ByRef` argument, which means that you can assign month names to each array item *within* the called sub procedure `createMonths` so that the calling procedure can actually use them, for instance to write them to a vertical range (e.g. starting at cell `A7`).

```
Option Explicit                             ' declaration head of code module

Sub PopulateMonthArray()
'[0] declare array at procedure level
Dim months(11) As String                    ' equals Dim months(0 to 11)
'Dim months(1 To 12) As String              ' alternative: declare a 1-based array

'[1] fill array items with month names passing array as (implicit) ByRef argument 
createMonths months                         ' << call sub createMonths 
'[2] write 1-dim array vertically to sheet (transposing output from a "flat" to a 2-dim array)   
Sheet1.Range("A7").Resize(Rowsize:=12).Value = Application.Transpose(months)
End Sub
```

**Sub procedure `createMonths`**

As you define a 0-based array `months(0 To 11)` and months count usually from 1 to 12 I added functionality to allow to create a 1-based array as well.

```
Sub createMonths(months)                     ' equals Sub createMonths(ByRef months)
    Dim countOffset As Long
    countOffset = IIf(LBound(months), 0, 1)  ' allow calculation of 0-based AND 1-based arrays
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(months) To UBound(months) ' loop through each array element
        months(i) = Application.Text(DateSerial(0, i + countOffset, 1), "mmmm")
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Simple alternative** /*Edit 2020-05-27*

If your intention is, however to make your months array disponible within other procedures **without** need to declare it in each procedure (neither at a global scope nor within a class definition), you could simply profit from a simple *workaround*:  insert a `Property Get` usable in standard modules, too - not only available in class modules btw. - *But note that you don't preserve ("retain") the array actually, you would rebuild it and possibly in a better readable way.*

```
Public Property Get Months()
    Dim tmp(1 To 12)                        ' I'd prefer a 1-based months array :-)
    createMonths tmp                        ' use the same procedure as above (or rebuild it code)
    Months = tmp                            ' return the Get value
End Property

Sub AnyOtherProcedure()
'no further declaration needed
Debug.Print Months(1)                       ' ~> January
Debug.Print Join(Months, ", ")              ' ~> January, February, ..., December
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, both.  I understand that the array dies once it hits "end sub" using the Step Through functionality, but is there a way to retain an array (i.e. store it) other than declaring it at the Global Level?  Is that the purpose of "createMonths months' ?  Would I then need to create a 3rd module to perform the action simulating "pasting" the months at the cursor selection?  I'll play around with the passing of the months functionality and stepping through.

Comment: Do you want to "save" the array values?

Comment: apologies for the delayed response.  Yes, I would like to save the array values.  However, that may be down the line in functionality that I have yet to learn.  Thank you.  I'll check off the green mark.